# How to deploy spring boot application into it self

Tags: java, spring-boot, devops, embedded-tomcat

I have a spring boot application that running on embedded tomcat with `java -jar app.jar` on a server away from my work office, and I haven't any ssh or other access to that server.
So when I want to install and run newer version of application, I should go to the server place, physically connect to server and then install and run newer version.

Is there a way to run newer version of application without going to the server place? for example, upload newer jar file into my running application, and itself update it.

**NOTE**

I don't have any access to server and cannot use and run any continous delivery tools like jenkins or other, because of IP and port restrictions.

Comment: From what I understood the server does not accept any inbound connections. Can it call any outbound service then?

Comment: @Jagger maybe can, do you know a way?

Comment: What about creating an app who has one endpoint, that accepts an upload. Make this upload be a JAR file, and have your app Runtime.exec() it. I would say it is not a really maintainable way of doing things, but it is doable. In short : make an app that can deploy an app. Whatever you do to achieve this, from a security point of view, this is also nightmar-ish. So you be warned :-)

Comment: @RasoolGhafari If the server can make an outbound connection for example to an SFTP server where you will store your jar file then write a script (`.bat`, `.sh` or whatever depending on the server's operating system) that will download the file and then redeploy the application with `java -jar your_app.jar`. You can use the hint from the forespeaker and run `Runtime.exec()` from a scheduled job in Spring Boot (`@Scheduled` annotation). Alternatively you can use some `SFTP` library in Java itself but then you would have the problem with stopping the application from itself.

Comment: @Jagger if the app is accessible through HTTP (if it's a Tomcat enabled SpringBoot app, you bet it is), then you do not even have to make an outbound connection, just HTTP POST your JAR. The only limits may be : HTTP request limits from the firewall/proxy/server (but you can just slice your uploads if it is the case), and security policy restrictions (Runtime.exec() might be forbidden by the Java runtime administrator).

Comment: @GPI you are completely right. One could just upload the file over HTTP(S).

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this a while back which worked out pretty well.

So you could create a super small app on the server(so small that it "never" needs to be updated) and have that monitor the versions and when a new version is available it could stop the real process and restart it with the new jar file.

I unfortunately don't have the code for that starter app, but it shouldn't take that long to write one that suits your needs

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install a Tomcat to the server and use it's management GUI to deploy the newer version of the app? It is a very old fashion but works well.
The only thing you will need to modify in your source code is to replace the `packaging` from `jar` to `war` in the pom.xml, so you can deploy it via Tomcat Manager.
This how the manager GUI looks like:
[image]

[You can learn more about the Tomcat Manager here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html).